# PDF of substraction of uniform

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution

> Let X and Y be i.i.d. Unif(0, 1), and let W = X − Y .
>    Find the PDF of W.

$0

$f(w)=\int_{0}^{1}f_X(x)f_Y(x-w)dx=\int_{0}^{1}f_Y(x-w)dx=?$

Comment: $f_X(x)=0 \not = 1$ when $x \lt 0$ or $x \gt 1$

Comment: @ Henry And then what? What to do next?

Comment: Next you use an indicator function as ChargeShivers did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
f_W(w) = \int_\mathbb{R} f_X(x)\; f_Y(x-w)\;\mathrm{d}x  
= \int_\mathbb{R} \mathbb{1}_{x\in(0,1)}  \mathbb{1}_{x-w\in(0,1)}\mathrm{d}x
= \int_{(0,1)\cap(w,1+w)} \mathrm{d}x = (1 -|w|)\mathbb{1}_{|w|<1} 
\end{align}

Comment: can you explain what you just did. I understand that $x \in (0,1)$ and $x-w \in (0,1)$ but what then? Why it is the same as the intersaction of $(0,1)$ and $(w,1+w)$. You just expressed x from it because the integration is with respect to x? One more thing: Why it is equal to $1-|w|1_{|w|<1}$??

Comment: The integrand is non-zero only if $x \in (0,1)$ **and** $x \in (w,1+w)$, which mean $x$ has to lie within the intersection of the two intervals. The value of the integral is the length of the intersection region. This can be found to be $$ \begin{cases} 1 -w & \textrm{ if } w \in [0,1] \\ 1 + w  & \textrm{ if } w \in [-1,0) \\ 0 & \textrm{ otherwise } \end{cases}$$ which can be written concisely as $(1 - |w|)\mathbb{1}_{|w|<1}$.